# Devise 3 Rails 4 Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is what I'm getting when signing up: `Unpermitted parameters: password_confirmation
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for User: email, password` I have installed everything and am trying devise out first time. I have created a model user and everything should be smooth. This is a fresh installation of devise first user sign up. No default code has been altered.
Please help!

PROBLEM SOLVED:
I added attr_accessible to my user.rb model

Comment: Did you restart the `rails server` after installing devise?

Comment: about 50 times since I installed devise.

Comment: Can you list the steps that you performed after installing `devise` gem? Like did you run "rails generate devise:install" then generate the devise model.

Comment: It installed correctly.The list of commands was from the github page. Look I just ran all of these commands again and when running rake db:migrate I got Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE users ADD email varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your User model and see if the parameters are accessible.

Keep in mind you don't need to name them, IE my User model looks like this with devise 3 and rails 4:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  validate :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: /[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}/ }
end
```

Solution Rahul is talking about doesn't make much sense as these parametters are already permitted on the requests, but in my case, I have an extra username attribute for this User model so I added to ApplicationController:

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
```

Comment: devise should be simple right. I am better of starting authentication from scratch!

Comment: it's pretty simple... in my opinion you are missing either the migration (rake db:migrate), or rails generate devise:install, or rails generate devise user, have you ran all those commands?

Comment: yes I have. It installed correctly. Look I just ran all of these commands and when running rake db:migrate I got Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: using gem 'rails', '4.0.0' , gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'protected_attributes' ? Should be compatible right?

Answer (score 1):

add following in your ApplicationController (if u have Rails4)

```
before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

#  method to sanitized params for devise user sign up
def update_sanitized_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email,:password, :password_confirmation)}
end
```

for more info see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started "Strong Parameters" section

Comment: sorry no change! unbelievable.. this is taking me all day. I've read a lot bout it and can't sort it.

Comment: do you know why this is happening?

Comment: are you creating record with your own controller or by using default devise registration controller..?

Comment: default registration controller.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is  getting this error still, check your form url path. I had copied the session_path into the form that should have used registration_path.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing my first use of Devise GEM (currently learning rails) with this exercise. In my case, I had the same error and it was a routing problem.

The issue was on a  **`form_for`**  in the **`new.index.html.erb`** of the **`devise/registrations`** views folder .

The form had a url: **`session_path(resource_name)`**, but in order to work it should point to **`registration_path(resource_name)`**.

I changed that and now it is working on heroku.

[This](https://github.com/muygrafico/deviseTest/blob/master/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb) is a link to the file.

And this is the exercise live on heroku: [devise.muga.com.co](http://devise.muga.com.co)

Comment: Jeeped, as you can see, this is an answer, not a question. Thanks to Raeen for making it shorter.